# Oracle Return Constant When Empty Result

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to figure out how to return a constant as a result when the result set is empty.

Example

A query would be:

```
select employee_id from employee where name = 'John_Doe';
```

For this case, John Doe does not exist in the system. Instead of returning an empty set, how could I return a constant, such as the number 0 instead? I've seen things with case statements, but I'm not sure how I would implement that.

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I'm faced with the problem of always returning exactly one row, I often use aggregation.  The following will return `NULL` if there is no match:

```
select max(employee_id)
from employee
where name = 'John_Doe';
```

The following returns 0:

```
select coalesce(max(employee_id), 0)
from employee
where name = 'John_Doe';
```

Comment: I'm sorry, my example wasn't clear. In my case, the column I would like to return is a String value. Is there any way to return a constant when the column being queried is a String?

Comment: Will your search criteria always return 1 or 0 rows? If so then you can still safely use `MAX()` on your string as well. If you could potentially match multiple rows, you would have to use a more complicated query to return the value you actually want.

Comment: @user1472409 . . . Just enclose the value in quotes, if you want a string constant.  But your question clearly says:  "such as the number 0 instead".